# Optimize the mysql query which runs longer

Tags: mysql

I have below query which runs for .046 seconds in console but through api call it runs for one min and then getting internal server error. don't know what the problem is. do I need to optimize the query... pls suggest a solution. I am using MySQL 5.5

```
Select distinctrow cus_id,set_id 
from orders 
where ord_dttm between DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%y-%m-01') 
and now() 
and ord_status <>"Cancelled";
```

I also tried indexing but no luck. indexing works only when the date range is 2 month for me

Comment: If the query itself runs fine (as per your statement), isn't the problem then most likely buried in the service's code somewhere?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299484/good-examples-of-database-questions-providing-some-sample-data-in-the-question - as it stands, we can't really help. At a minimum, please provide the table structure and query plan.

Comment: As Sirko already mentioned, the problem is not the query. What Language with which API are you using?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the comments. We are using java with REST API

Comment: in which language you are made this REST API ?

Answer (score 1):

try like this,

```
Select distinctrow cus_id,set_id 
from orders 
where ord_dttm >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%Y-%m-01')
and ord_status <> "Cancelled";
```

and if you are made this API in `PHP`, calculate date in PHP var, then you can use direct `date` like:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-12 months"));

$sql = "Select distinctrow cus_id,set_id 
from orders 
where ord_dttm >= '". $date ."' AND ord_status <> 'Cancelled';"
```

this will also improve your query fetch speed.

Answer (score 0):

Use a capital Y, else it will be very old date:

```
mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%y-%m-01');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%y-%m-01') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 18-12-01                                          |
+---------------------------------------------------+

mysql> select DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%Y-%m-01');
+---------------------------------------------------+
| DATE_FORMAT(NOW()- interval 12 month, '%Y-%m-01') |
+---------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-12-01                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

If that does not suffice, please provide `SHOW CREAT TABLE` and the size of the table.